# что происходит с typescript при билде?

Tags: javascript, typescript, build

Нигде не мог найти внятную инфу о том, что происходить с typescript при билде проекта? Нагружает ли он бандл или нет, он преобразуется в js или просто испаряется?)
Наверное глупый вопрос, но все же хотелось поподробнее узнать на счет этого, может быть кто-то сможет кинуть статью для прочтения.

Comment: Мягко говоря, typeScript удаляется(как вы указали, испаряется)

Comment: @SwaD, ну очень мягко)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну открываешь [плейграунд](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) и экспериментируешь.

Тайпскрипт старается избегать рантайм-фич, но есть как минимум енумы, которые компилируются специфическим образом.

Вся информация о типах безвозвратно удаляется.

В зависимости от target код может быть модифицировна для соответствия более раннему стандарту js. В таком случае будут добавлены runtime-хелперы.

Как правило, вместе с тайпскриптом подключают полифилы - естественно, они остаются.